# JST 1.25mm connector soldering

Tags: connector, soldering, surface-mount

I'd like to SMD solder the JST 1.25mm connector below with horizontal orientation aligning it to the side of the PCB (ie. in the end the male header should be plugged to the connector from the side of the PCB not from above the PCB). As visible the pins on the rear side are raised from the bottom plane of the connector so they don't touch the PCB when the connector is layed on it.

Is this connector meant to be soldered the way I described, or is it just a through hole connector meant to be soldered with a vertical orientation? If the former is true, how to solder it, just put enough solder paste/tin under the pins to fill the space?

What is the proper name for this type of connector?

The product link where I bought the connector:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/231443803216

Rear side-1:
[image: Rear-1]
Rear side-2:
[image: Rear-2]
Bottom side:
[image: Bottom]
Front side:
[image: Front]

Comment: @peufeu, does your solution mean that the plastic part of the connector lies on the PCB, or that it's off the PCB and it's only the pins that are on the PBC?

Comment: It looks like a Molex connector to me or similar knock-off. http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=wire_to_board_connectors&channel=products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this connector meant to be soldered the way I described

Not really, but don't let that stop you.

> or is it just a through hole connector meant to be soldered with a vertical orientation?

Yes.

> If the former is true, how to solder it, just put enough solder paste/tin under the pins to fill the space?

- Put pads on the edge of your board, something like the edge of an ISA PC card.
- Put one or two plated through vias in each pad
- Hold connector in place, flush with board
- Solder

Solder will wick into the vias, and this will increase mechanical strength. It should be a bit stronger than simply relying on pad adhesion onto the PCB.

This isn't something you'd do in a fabrication run, because it has to be hand soldered, but it'll be much stronger than a wimpy SMD connector. Like the micro-USB in your smartphone/tablet which falls off the board if you plug in the charger wrong.

I do it all the time with 0.1" headers for prototyping, and the headers will bend before the solder breaks.

Comment: ADDITION.. Double check the manufacturers catalog. They often supply a 90 degree version of connectors like this. That provides greater mechanical stability.

Comment: Ok. I wonder what are all the mounting options for this sort of connector. I can imagine the following three: THT vertical, THT horizontal with 90 degree pins, SMD horizontal with THT or SMD clamp pins for robustness.